# If meta_data <= 50

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to automate the delivery (free above 50) message in my template. Currently I'm echo'ing the normal price & discount price (if available) which results in digits.

I have a post with Normal_price = 55 / Discount_price = 38

I'm new to PHP but tried the following:

```
<?php $discount = (get_post_meta($post->ID, 'Discount_price', true));
      $normal = (get_post_meta($post->ID, 'Normal_price', true));

     if $discount = (>= 50) {
     echo 'under 50 euro';
     }

     else if $normal = (>= 50) {
     echo 'under 50 euro';
     }

     else
    {
    echo 'above 50 euro';
    }



?>
```

How do I declare $discount = post_meta 'Discount_Price'?

Comment: That isn't standard PHP syntax: `if ($discount >= 50) {`

Comment: Please watch some basic php tutorials. We are not a school here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you really want to do is:

```
$discountPrice = (get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'Discount_price', true));
$normalPrice = (get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'Normal_price', true));
// NOTE: get_the_ID() will only work if you are inside the loop

if ( $discountPrice <= 50 ) {
    // 50 euro or less
    echo '50 euro or less';
} else if ( $normalPrice <= 50 ) {
    // 50 euro or less
    echo '50 euro or less';
} else {
    // over 50 euro
    echo 'over 50 euro';
}
```

You've got your operators reversed on your compares, which is part of the problem, but also `$discount = (>=50)` will not work. As one of the comments mentioned, that's not the correct syntax.

It won't solve the problem, but just as an FYI: Using a single `=` sets a value. Using `==` compares a value.

Comment: Yup, this doesn't work BUT it helps me understand way better. Thanks Mike!